# C# Method Overload and Extension Methods

Tags: c#

I've created the following extension method to log4net's `ILog` interface:

```
public static void Debug(this ILog log, IDiagnosticMessage message)
{
    // do some stuff with the IDiagnosticMessage and end up calling ILog.Logger.Log with the result
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to want to use this method. When I call `ILog.Debug` with an `IDiagnosticMessage` parameter it always uses log4net's `ILog.Debug(object)` overload.

Short of explicitly calling the static method does anybody have any ideas what I can do to make the compiler call my extension instead of the interface method?

Comment: Give it a different name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13524408/1583

Comment: An original method with a matching signature will always be executed in favour of an extension method - why can't you use a different method name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899539/is-there-any-way-in-c-sharp-to-override-a-class-method-with-an-extension-method

Comment: No reason at all, just looks nicer :)! I assumed that extension methods could override instance methods! Should have read the language spec before posting... 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx if anybody's interested!

Comment: I've voted to close the question as duplicate, thanks!